# Do quasi-isometries of Gromov hyperbolic groups coarsely preserve the group operation?

Tags: metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and $H$ a [hyperbolic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_group) in the sense of Gromov, with a fixed word metric $d$.

Let $\varphi : G\to H$ be a [quasi-isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry). Does there exist uniform constant $C> 0$ such that for any $g,h \in G$, $$d(\varphi(g)\varphi(h), \varphi(gh)) \leq C? \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

***Discussion:***

It is not too hard to see that there are quasi-isometries of non-hyperbolic spaces which do not coarsely preserve the group operation. For example, one can take the map $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, $(r, \theta) \mapsto (r, \log(1+r))$, where $(r,\theta)$ are polar coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2, +)$ is considered as the additive group.

On the other hand, the [Morse Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry#Quasigeodesics_and_the_Morse_lemma) states that any quasi-geodesic in a hyperbolic space is a uniform distance away from a geodesic connecting its endpoints ("uniform" for a given choice of quasi-isometry constants and the hyperbolicity constant). Again, our example above shows that this fails badly in non-hyperbolic spaces.

***Questions:***

Is Morse Lemma enough to coarsely preserve the group operation under quasi-isometries? Or is there an insightful example of a quasi-isometry of hyperbolic groups where $(*)$ fails miserably?

Is there a natural condition that one can put on groups $G,H$ which would force $(*)$ to hold? (Short of something trivial like requiring one - and thus both - of $G$ and $H$ to be finite.)

Comment: An example: $G=\mathbf{Z}$, $\varphi(n)=n$ for $n\le 0$, $\varphi(n)=2n$ for $n\ge 0$.

Comment: For free groups and surface groups the QI group lacks of rigidity. While for, say, the quaternionic hyperbolic space (and hence lattices in $\mathrm{Sp}(n\ge 2,1)$, every QI is at bounded distance from a unique isometry. You might want to translates what it then means in terms of the lattice. Possibly there are infinite discrete hyperbolic groups for which every QI is at bounded distance from a left translation, although I don't have an example in mind.

Comment: Thanks both. What I'm really secretly asking about is whether, given two quasi-isometric hyperbolic groups $G$ and $G'$, and a qi-embedded subgroup $H$ of $G$, is there a way of obtaining a subgroup of $G'$ which is qi to $H$? Anyway, I think that is definitely something more appropriate for  Mathoverflow.

Comment: This secret question, I think, is quite difficult. Consider the fact that until the work of Kahn and Markovic about 10 years ago, it was unknown if all uniform lattices in O(3,1) contain surface subgroups. At the same time, it is trivial that all these lattices are qi to each other and **some** contain surface subgroups. (And if a group is qi to a surface group then it is virtually a surface group.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class of examples of infinite hyperbolic groups $G$ such that every self-quasi-isometry $G\to G$ is at finite distance from a left-translation by an element of $G$.

Start with a compact connected $n$-dimensional manifold  $M$ with nonempty boundary which admits a hyperbolic metric such that the boundary is totally-geodesic. Then the universal cover $\tilde{M}$ of $M$ is isometric to a certain convex subset $C\subset {\mathbb H}^n$ in the hyperbolic $n$-space, $n\ge 3$. The fundamental group $\pi(M)$ of $M$ acts on $C$ isometrically as the  group of covering transformations $\Pi$ for $\tilde{M}\to M$. Let $G$ denote the maximal subgroup of isometries of ${\mathbb H}^n$ preserving $C$. Since $C$ has infinitely many boundary components, the subgroup $G$ is discrete; it acts on $C$ cocompactly since $\Pi< G$. Thus, $G$ is a hyperbolic group. As it turns out, every quasi-isometry $C\to C$ is within finite distance from an element of $G$, see

*Frígerio, Roberto*, [**Commensurability of hyperbolic manifolds with geodesic boundary**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10711-005-9028-x), Geom. Dedicata 118, 105-131 (2006). [ZBL1096.32014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1096.32014).

Thus, $G$ satisfies the required property.

As for the original question, the answer is negative even when $G=H$, unless $G$ is finite. I'll prove it only for nonelementary hyperbolic groups $G$. Let $x\in G$ be an element of infinite order and $L_x: G\to G$ be the left translation of $G$ by $x$ ($L_x(y)=xy$). Then $L_x$ is an isometry of $G$. However, $L_x$ does not satisfy (*) for any constant $C$. Indeed, apply $(*)$ with $h=g^{-1}$, then you get
$$
d(gxg^{-1}, 1) = d(xgxg^{-1}, x)=d(xgxg^{-1}, xgg^{-1})\le C
$$
for all $g\in G$. But if $x, g$ do not commute and $g$ has infinite order, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} d(g^nxg^{-n}, 1)=\infty. 
$$

As for your "secret question", it sounds very difficult. I am sure it has negative answer (in general) but I do not know how to construct an example.

Comment: That's great, thanks. And the fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty} d(g^nxg^{-n},1) = \infty$ for $g,x$ of infinite order follows from hyperbolicity ?

Comment: @24601: Yes: Consider the axis $A$ of $x$ ($A$ is uniformly close to a geodesic in the Cayley graph of $G$) and apply $g^n$ to it: Since $x$ and $g$ do not virtually commute, $g$ will not preserve $A$; It follows that the sequene $A_n=g^n(A)$ converges to a single point in the Gromov boundary of $G$. But $A_n$ is the axis of $g^nxg^{-1}$. Hence, the claim.